# strategies for calling ASP.Net WebAPI services inside Polymer element

Tags: asp.net-web-api, polymer-1.0

I'm getting up to speed with Polymer as a means to creating web components.  I love the idea of creating HTML tags for embedding functionality.

I've been Googling around for examples of calling ASP.Net WEB API services inside a Polymer element and cannot find a good example.  Can anyone recommend approaches or provide links, examples of how they've consumed ASP.Net WebAPI services from inside a Polymer element please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the iron-ajax component to get data from my ASP.Net API.
There's a good YouTube demo created recently:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1eR_3KqJms&list=PLOU2XLYxmsII5c3Mgw6fNYCzaWrsM3sMN

Comment: are there any caching strategies for the JSON data returned when using iron-ajax?

Comment: I wish there was some more advanced automated caching. I haven't seen any Polymer based caching of iron-ajax. Not sure if using the offline first polymer starter kit would help. You probably could store the `iron-ajax` `last-request` data using `iron-localstorage` and write your own cache code.

Comment: I use AngularJS where services are singletons, so sometimes I cache the results of WebAPI calls in a variable in the service.  I suppose there's no 'singleton' concept with polymer.  Thanks again for your help.